# Calculate linear phase when given in decibel

Tags: operational-amplifier, decibel

The datasheet of the [LT6230](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/623012fc.pdf) shows the op amp's phase lag in decibels (page 14).

[image: Open Loop Gain LT6230]

The datasheet does not give a formula to recalculate the angle in degrees, so can I just assume the following being the correct conversion?
$$
[\text{Phase}] = 10^{\frac{X_{\text{dB}}}{20}}
$$

I'm afraid, the numbers do not really check out: From 80dB to 0dB, the phase margin is 1000° which seems to be a bit high for an operational amplifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the data sheet has screwed up. The right hand vertical scale should not be "Phase (dB)" but "Phase (degrees)". This sort of thing happens now and then.

How do I know? I know this because the mid-band phase of an op-amp is usually about 90 degrees (as shown at 100 kHz). There is also the correct axis shown on page 15 in a similar graph!

Comment: also, if you look at the datasheet the LT6230-10 section has the correct axis title while the LT6230/LT6231/LT6232 is in err

Comment: I think I may have just also pointed that out LOL @JonRB

Comment: oh yes :) just saw that

Answer (score 5):

Taking as a clue that the phase lag at low frequency is about 90 'somethings', we can safely assume that the phase axis numbers are in degrees, and the dB is a typo.

Comment: was just about to write that